# EMET is deprecated, which DLL implements the ring3 mitigation?

Tags: anti-exploitation

I'm reading this document: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/exploit-protection-reference?view=o365-worldwide

In older OS, EMET injects a DLL into the process. On latest Windows EMET is implemented by windows directly. I'm wondering which DLL implements it? I'll then look into it with IDA.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a number of different DLLs, in addition to kernel features (for things that don't need to be implemented in userspace, like W^X). I strongly doubt there's just a single one.